# local variable 'type' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

Why I'm getting this error?

> local variable 'type' referenced before assignment

**Code:**

```
try:
    if type(meeting.modified_date) != bool:
        //code

except Exception as e:
    raise ValidationError(_(str(e)))

finally:
    type = None
    if 1:
        type = 'auto'
    else:
        type = 'manual'
```

I was thinking some local variable creating this error but after debugging I come to know that this **`if`** condition creating an error because of this **`type()`**.

Comment: Is there also type variable in same function or maybe even class, Then it wil be treated as local variable not as global

Comment: No @Paxmees there is no such variable with in method

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is because you assign the global function type to a value in your code. If you do this, then the global function type will be overwritten to be a variable even before the actual assignment in the scope of the name space. Because the python interpreter now treats type as a local variable instead of the global function it is not assigned when you try to call the global function (which is treated as a local variable).

Solution: do not assign names of global functions to variables and rename the variable "type" to something else e.g., object_type.

I mean the code example is basically provided by @Paxmees in the replies. His explanation is a bit difficult to understand. But if you want to see one:

```
def example_error(var):
    if type(var) == bool:
        pass
    #this produces the error, because you overwrite global function type
    type = "string"

def example_fixed(var):
    if type(var) == bool:
        pass
    #fixed do not overwrite global function type:
    type_of_var = "string"
```

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support the given answer explaining show how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get that error.

```py
def _something(self, meeting):
    if type(meeting.modified_date) != bool:
        pass
    #rename it
    type = "small"
```

Edit:

```py
try:
    if type(meeting.modified_date) != bool:
        //code

except Exception as e:
    raise ValidationError(_(str(e)))

finally:
    #this is local variable and the fix is 
    record_type = None
    if 1:
        record_type = 'auto'
    else:
        record_type = 'manual'
#and later where type is used it should renamed aswell
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty values on record attributes in Odoo recordsets will always be falsy, except for number fields like float or integer. They will have the value zero and this also is falsy, but zero values can have a meaning in some contexts, so you should always think about the if conditions when checking number values.

Anyways, you can just change your if condition to

```py
if meeting.modified_date:
```

, because non set date fields are falsy and set date fields are truthy.

Comment: You're right but why python failed to differentiate between variable and method.

Comment: hard to say without seeing the code at all :-/